# Android: using flex for android

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I am planning to build android applications using adobe flex. But as per my knowledge we dont need to use android sdk for this purpose. I have created hello world app using flex,It is completely different from creating apps using android sdk. Is there any way to use flex widgets with android sdk(I mean instead of using android UI widgets can I use flex widgets) .please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no,  Air apps don't have that native capability.

However there is a way to get around some limitations.
James Ward wrote a great post about it.
http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subclass View for each "page" of your Android app.  But beyond that, you probably don't *have* to use the lightweight, performant mobile versions of things like buttons if you don't mind having an app that is not lightweight and performant.